# Setting css property to 'auto' gives height of 0 in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

When I try to set the height to a div to auto in jquery and try to calculate its height again will give me a 0 as result. why is this so?

```
$('#test').css('height','auto')

$('#test').height(); // 0
```

How can I calculate its height instead?

**EDIT**

This is the javascript code that I am running:

```
function visitFix() {
    $('.visit').find('.profileDetail').each(function () {
        console.log($(this).height()); //24
        $(this).css('height', 'auto');
       console.log($(this).height()); // 0
    });
}
```

This is what the DOM-tree looks like:

```
<td class="profileView">
    <div class="profileContent">Purpose: </div>
    <div class="profileDetail" style="height: auto;">Program Participant Volunteer Rejuvenation Participant General Visit </div>
</td>
```

The out put is 24 and then 0.

Comment: perhaps your `#test` has no content

Comment: What's in the div? Show us te code

Comment: is `#test` floating or has absolute positioning?

Comment: #test has content. I added the actual content to the question.

Answer (score 1):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/zS7kd/

You can use `.height(),` `.innerHeight()` or `outerHeight()` based on what you need.

http://api.jquery.com/height/

[image]

`.height() -` returns the height of element excludes padding, border and margin.

`.innerHeight() -` returns the height of element includes padding but excludes border and margin.

`.outerHeight() -` returns the height of the div including border but excludes margin.

`.outerHeight(true) -` returns the height of the div including margin.

Answer (score 0):

when we set in

#### css

```
{height:auto}
```

#### html

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

#### jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
        alert($("#test").height());
    });
```

then output is **0**

```
<div id="test">dsdsdsd</div>
```

now

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
        alert($("#test").height());
    });
```

then out put is **20**

so when we set height :auto then it automatic calculate height

and you want to get height by padding and margin then there is more function like

References:

**[.innerHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/)** - returns the height of element includes padding but excludes border and margin.

**[.outerHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/)** - returns the height of the div including border but excludes margin.

Answer (score 0):

I find that in some scripts where I've set a height and need to resize, due to new incoming content, that you first should remove any set heights first.  Then pull the outerHeight() or innerHeight() as needed.